# How to view facebook messages on Safari iOS / iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, facebook, mobile-safari

Without using the Messenger app for Facebook. How can I view Facebook messages on iOS Safari?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### iOS13+

Tap on `AA` icon on the top left and tap `Request Desktop Website`. Now go to the messages section and read your messages

[image]

### iOS 12

Tap and hold the refresh button untill the below options come. Select the `Request Desktop Site` and boom just tap on messages button and check your messages.

[image]

Comment: so sad it is not working anymore.